# SharePoint Designer creating gallery with email alert

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, alert, web-part-gallery

I need help in configuring Add or Change Lookup in Workflow Settings. Basically, I want to create a gallery (application) with pictures. After the picture will be added to the page, work flow will send @ with information that there is a new picture in the gallery.

Tried to do it by myself (checked similar topics) but sharepoint don't send msg to receivers.

I believe that I have a problem with configuration section Add or Change Lookup and selecting correct data.

Also, it would be great if someone describes whole process step by step. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your scenario, I think no need to create an alert using SharePoint Designer workflow where you can easily use the OOTB `Alerts`.

[image]

**Steps:**

- Open your library that holds the images.
- From the above ribbon > Library Tab > Click `Alert Me` > `Set an alert on this library`.
- Configure your alert based on your requirements.

  - At `Send Alerts To` specify the receptions email.
  - At `Change Type`, Specify the type of changes that you want to be alerted to.

[image]

---

**Note:** Don't forget to configure Outgoing E-Mail settings in SharePoint Servers to **avoid missing Alert button**

- Go to Central Administration > System Settings > Configure Outgoing Email Settings
- Enter the FQDN of the local SMTP server (Mail.MQassas.local)
- Enter the From and Reply-to Address
- Click OK to save settings.

I wrote the detail steps at [THE “ALERT ME” BUTTON IS NOT VISIBLE ON THE RIBBON IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/26/the-alert-me-button-is-not-visible-on-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: I was trying to use SharePoint Designer because I don't know why i don't see alert option : [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwkkh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwkkh.png)